# How can I implement Lazy Loading with Grid

Tags: sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, performance

I have grid with more than 1 million records, While page Load i needs to bind all the values into grid. The Grid needs to have multiple filter

Please suggest which way to bind all the records in grid and which is the best client side grids suitable for this scenarios

Comment: `lakh` isn't an English word. How many records do you have? Anyway, even if you have 100 rows, lazy loading is a good idea. Almost all JavaScript grids support, which makes this a bit broad. At the very least you need a controller action that takes a page size and page number and executes the appropriate query eg with LINQ it would be `.Skip(pageSize*pageNumber).Take(pageSize);`

Comment: you should use datatable and only get 10 records at a time using serveside call and display pagination like lacks of records and when select next page get another 11 to 20 rocords from database. so it get 10 records at a time and display pagination of 1 lack rocords

Comment: But the grid having multiple column filters like Auto complete search, drop down and etc, for this kind of scenario what needs to Do

Comment: 1 million records is 999,950 too many records to pass to a single page.